# Overriding Enum __call__ method

Tags: python, enums

I have an `Enum` like so:

```
from enum import Enum

class Animal(Enum):

     cat = 'meow'
     dog = 'woof'
     never_heard_of = None

     def talk(self):
         print(self.value)
```

I would like to override the `__call__` method so that a call like          `Animal('hee-haw')` returns `Animals.never_heard_of` or `None` instead of raising `ValueError`. I would rather avoid a `try` statement everytime I call the `Animal`.

What would be a pure Python equivalent of `Enum.__call__` ?

Comment: Why don't you just use e.g. `dict(cat='meow', dog='woof').get(whatever)`? This seems like a weird use of an enumerator.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I was after an immutable set of constants. If a constant is not defined it returns None. I can have logic gates into my program to tell me about which spreadsheet software I will interact with.

Comment: Please give some context, otherwise this is likely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2017-03-30**

With Python 3.6 (and [`aenum 2.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup>) you can specify a `_missing_` method that will be called to give your class one last chance before raising `ValueError`.  So now you can do:

```
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, name):
        return cls.never_heard_of
```

---

*Original Answer*

To be clear: you want the `__call__` that is associated with `Animal()` which is actually on the metaclass (`EnumMeta` in `enum.py`).

This is a bag of worms you don't want to get in to, as it is very easy to break things.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107853/208880) for more details, but the simple solution is to create a `get` method for your `Animal` enum:

```
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name):
        try:
            return cls[name]
        except KeyError:
            return cls.never_heard_of
```

and then `Animal.get('wolf')` will return `Animal.never_heard_of`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: That sounds a bit like Pandora's box but without Hope at the end... Thanks for this useful piece of advice.