# When should I subclass EnumMeta instead of Enum?

Tags: python, enums, metaclass

In [this article](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/enum_creation.html) Nick Coghlan talks about some of the design decisions that went in to the [PEP 435 `Enum` type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/), and how `EnumMeta` can be subclassed to provide a different `Enum` experience.

However, the advice I give (and I am the primary stdlib `Enum` author) about using a metaclass is it should not be done without a really good reason -- such as not being able to accomplish what you need with a class decorator, or a dedicated function to hide any ugliness; and in my own work I've been able to do whatever I needed simply by using `__new__`, `__init__`, and/or normal class/instance methods when creating the `Enum` class:

- [`Enum` with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680080/python-enums-with-attributes)
- [Handling missing members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444002/overriding-enum-call-method)
- [class constants that are not `Enum` members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911188/is-it-possible-to-define-a-class-constant-inside-an-enum)

And then there is this cautionary tale of being careful when delving into `Enum`, with and without metaclass subclassing:

- [Is it possible to override `__new__` in an enum to parse strings to an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107853/208880)

Given all that, when would I need to fiddle with `EnumMeta` itself?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best cases I have seen so far for subclassing `EnumMeta` comes from these four questions:

- [A more pythonic way to define an enum with dynamic members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43096541/208880)
- [Prevent invalid enum attribute assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54274002/208880)
- [Create an abstract Enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56131308/208880)
- [Invoke a function when an enum member is accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62299740/208880)

We'll examine the dynamic member case further here.

---

First, a look at the code needed when not subclassing `EnumMeta`:

**The stdlib way**

```
from enum import Enum
import json

class BaseCountry(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, record):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member.country_name = record['name']
        member.code = int(record['country-code'])
        member.abbr = record['alpha-2']
        member._value_ = member.abbr, member.code, member.country_name
        if not hasattr(cls, '_choices'):
            cls._choices = {}
        cls._choices[member.code] = member.country_name
        cls._choices[member.abbr] = member.country_name
        return member                
    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

Country = BaseCountry(
        'Country',
        [(rec['alpha-2'], rec) for rec in json.load(open('slim-2.json'))],
        )
```

**The [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) way** <sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup>

```
from aenum import Enum, MultiValue
import json

class Country(Enum, init='abbr code country_name', settings=MultiValue):
    _ignore_ = 'country this'  # do not add these names as members
    # create members
    this = vars()
    for country in json.load(open('slim-2.json')):
        this[country['alpha-2']] = (
                country['alpha-2'],
                int(country['country-code']),
                country['name'],
                )
    # have str() print just the country name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name
```

---

The above code is fine for a one-off enumeration -- but what if creating Enums from JSON files was common for you?  Imagine if you could do this instead:

```
class Country(JSONEnum):
    _init_ = 'abbr code country_name'  # remove if not using aenum
    _file = 'some_file.json'
    _name = 'alpha-2'
    _value = {
            1: ('alpha-2', None),
            2: ('country-code', lambda c: int(c)),
            3: ('name', None),
            }
```

As you can see:

- `_file` is the name of the json file to use
- `_name` is the path to whatever should be used for the name
- `_value` is a dictionary mapping paths to values<sup>3</sup>
- `_init_` specifies the attribute names for the different value components (if using `aenum`)

The JSON data is taken from https://github.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes -- here is a short excerpt:

> [{"name":"Afghanistan","alpha-2":"AF","country-code":"004"},
>
> {"name":"Åland Islands","alpha-2":"AX","country-code":"248"},
>
> {"name":"Albania","alpha-2":"AL","country-code":"008"},
>
> {"name":"Algeria","alpha-2":"DZ","country-code":"012"}]

Here is the `JSONEnumMeta` class:

```
class JSONEnumMeta(EnumMeta):

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, cls, bases, **kwds):
        # return a standard dictionary for the initial processing
        return {}

    def __init__(cls, *args , **kwds):
        super(JSONEnumMeta, cls).__init__(*args)

    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict, **kwds):
        import json
        members = []
        missing = [
               name
               for name in ('_file', '_name', '_value')
               if name not in clsdict
               ]
        if len(missing) in (1, 2):
            # all three must be present or absent
            raise TypeError('missing required settings: %r' % (missing, ))
        if not missing:
            # process
            name_spec = clsdict.pop('_name')
            if not isinstance(name_spec, (tuple, list)):
                name_spec = (name_spec, )
            value_spec = clsdict.pop('_value')
            file = clsdict.pop('_file')
            with open(file) as f:
                json_data = json.load(f)
            for data in json_data:
                values = []
                name = data[name_spec[0]]
                for piece in name_spec[1:]:
                    name = name[piece]
                for order, (value_path, func) in sorted(value_spec.items()):
                    if not isinstance(value_path, (list, tuple)):
                        value_path = (value_path, )
                    value = data[value_path[0]]
                    for piece in value_path[1:]:
                        value = value[piece]
                    if func is not None:
                        value = func(value)
                    values.append(value)
                values = tuple(values)
                members.append(
                    (name, values)
                    )
        # get the real EnumDict
        enum_dict = super(JSONEnumMeta, metacls).__prepare__(cls, bases, **kwds)
        # transfer the original dict content, _items first
        items = list(clsdict.items())
        items.sort(key=lambda p: (0 if p[0][0] == '_' else 1, p))
        for name, value in items:
            enum_dict[name] = value
        # add the members
        for name, value in members:
            enum_dict[name] = value
        return super(JSONEnumMeta, metacls).__new__(metacls, cls, bases, enum_dict, **kwds)

# for use with both Python 2/3
JSONEnum = JSONEnumMeta('JsonEnum', (Enum, ), {})
```

A few notes:

- `JSONEnumMeta.__prepare__` returns a normal `dict`
- `EnumMeta.__prepare__` is used to get an instance of `_EnumDict` -- this is the proper way to get one
- keys with a leading underscore are passed to the real `_EnumDict` first as they may be needed when processing the enum members
- Enum members are in the same order as they were in the file

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

<sup>2</sup> This requires `aenum 2.0.5+`.

<sup>3</sup> The keys are numeric to keep multiple values in order should your `Enum` need more than one.

Comment: What I cannot understand is why using EnumMeta over classical inheritance?

Comment: @jossefaz: Do you mean why not just add an `Enum.from_json()` class method?  You certainly could.

Comment: What about the case of "customizing dunder methods such as `__contains__` so you can write things like `3 in Color`? (in this case, `Color` being an `IntEnum`). Is this possible without subclassing `EnumMeta`?

Comment: @MestreLion: using `3 in Color` would require a change to `EnumMeta`.  You could make a `classmethod`, though, to do the same thing with different syntax; e.g. `Color.contains(3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So for the sake of completeness, could this case could be added to your _"The best (and only) cases I have seen so far for subclassing `EnumMeta`..."_ list? For me is still confusing to tell which changes require fiddling with `EnumMeta` and which don't. Btw, congrats on both `enum` and `aenum`!

Comment: @MestreLion: Rather than try and list every possible situation where `EnumMeta` would have to be subclassed, I removed the `(and only)` clause.  Note that in 3.12, `3 in Color` will return `True` if any member of `Color` has the value of `3` (`Enum`, `IntEnum`, etc.).