# How to get random value of attribute of Enum on each iteration?

Tags: python, random, lambda, enums

I have created such `Enum` object:

```
class Gender(Enum):
    FEMALE = 'female'
    MALE = 'male'
    RANDOM = random.choice([FEMALE, MALE])
```

and i want to get really random value each time, but it does not work:

```
>>> class Gender(Enum):
...    MALE = 'male'
...    FEMALE = 'female'
...    RANDOM = choice([MALE, FEMALE])
... 
>>> Gender.RANDOM
<Gender.MALE: 'male'>
>>> Gender.RANDOM
<Gender.MALE: 'male'>
>>> Gender.RANDOM
<Gender.MALE: 'male'>
>>> Gender.RANDOM
<Gender.MALE: 'male'>
```

I have also tried use lambda, but it's looks not so good, although it works:

```
Gender.RANDOM()
```

Are there other way to get random values each time, without using lambda expressions?

We use this enum object as default value of the argument of the some method that's why it should be an attribute, not a function, because when we use `Gender.FEMALE` it is not a function, it's an attribute and `Gender.RANDOM` should be an attribute too:

```
def full_name(gender=Gender.FEMALE):
    ...


def full_name(gender=Gender.RANDOM):
    ...
```

Comment: Default attributes are only evaluated once (when you define the function), so the random value will only be random the one time, and every time you call that function you will get the same initial value.

Comment: That's usual behavior which i want to change.

Comment: That is a Python fundamental behavior and you cannot change it.

Comment: I was referring to the workaround. Of course i can't change the Python and i don't want to do it.

Comment: What workaround? `def full_name(gender=Gender.RANDOM):` is not a workaround.

Comment: @EthanFurman I actually can do it using descriptor `classproperty` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189699/how-to-make-a-class-property) answer, but I was hoping for a simpler solution that would be much Pythonic.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried a way with [metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python). And it works!

```
import random
import enum
class RANDOM_ATTR(enum.EnumMeta):
    @property
    def RANDOM(self):
        return random.choice([Gender.MALE, Gender.FEMALE])


class Gender(enum.Enum,metaclass=RANDOM_ATTR): #this syntax works for python3 only
    FEMALE = 'female'
    MALE = 'male'


print(Gender.RANDOM)   #prints male or female randomly
```

Here by making `RANDOM_ATTR` the metaclass of `Gender`, `Gender` is like an object of class `RANDOM_ATTR`, so `Gender` has the [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) `RANDOM`.

However,the below code you described in your question doesn't work the way you expect.

```
def full_name(gender=Gender.RANDOM):
    ...
```

The `RANDOM` property will be called only once. To know why, please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145781/8524503). Default arguments are like attributes to function, which will be initialised only once.

For that i would suggest you do something like this:

```
def full_name(gender=None):
    gender = gender or Gender.RANDOM
    ...
```

Comment: While it does work, I'm down-voting because `EnumMeta` should only be subclassed when necessary and there are other ways to solve this problem. See [When should I subclass `EnumMeta`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43730305/208880) for details on `EnumMeta` subclassing.  However, since this was a successful effort I am offering a bounty on it.

Answer (score 14):

As others have said, the best way is to just make `random()` be a method on your enum class to make it clear that `RANDOM` is not a member.

However, since I like puzzles:

```
from enum import Enum
import random

class enumproperty(object):
    "like property, but on an enum class"

    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, instance, ownerclass=None):
        if ownerclass is None:
            ownerclass = instance.__class__
        return self.fget(ownerclass)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise AttributeError("can't set pseudo-member %r" % self.name)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        raise AttributeError("can't delete pseudo-member %r" % self.name)

class Gender(Enum):
    FEMALE = 'female'
    MALE = 'male'
    @enumproperty
    def RANDOM(cls):
        return random.choice(list(cls.__members__.values()))
```

---

In your `full_name` definition, using `Gender.RANDOM` as a default value will not get you what you want.  The standard for such is:

```
def full_name(gender=None):
    if gender is None:
        gender = Gender.RANDOM   # we get `MALE` or `FEMALE`, not `RANDOM`
```

Which is going to be confusing to the reader.  This is much better using a normal method:

```
def full_name(gender=None):
    if gender is None:
        gender = Gender.random()
```

Comment: You are right. It's much clearer, than using Gender.RANDOM as default value. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You probably should create a method in your `Enum` to obtain a random gender:

```
import random
import enum

class Gender(enum.Enum):
    FEMALE = 'female'
    MALE = 'male'

    @classmethod
    def get_gender(cls):
        return random.choice([Gender.FEMALE, Gender.MALE])

Gender.get_gender()
```

Comment: We use this enum object as default value of some method, and it should be `Gender.RANDOM`, not `Gender.get_random()` or `Gender.RANDOM()`. It's for clear API.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a method random, instead to save the value directly in the variable, because if you do that, the value will never change:

**If you DON'T WANT A FUNCTION**

import random
import enum

```
class Gender(enum.Enum):

  MALE = 'male'
  FEMALE = 'female'
  RANDOM = random.choice([MALE, FEMALE])


  def __getattribute__(self,item):
    if item == "RANDOM":
      Gender.RANDOM = random.choice([self.MALE, self.FEMALE])
      return Gender.RANDOM
    else:
      return object.__getattribute__(self, item)

gender = Gender()
```

look:

```
   gender.RANDOM
=> 'female'
   gender.RANDOM
=> 'male'
   gender.RANDOM
=> 'male'
   gender.RANDOM
=> 'male'
   gender.RANDOM
=> 'female'
   gender.RANDOM
=> 'male'
   gender.RANDOM
=> 'male'
   gender.RANDOM
=> 'female'
```

Comment: I tried this, it's works, but methods with uppercase is looks ugly.

Comment: @LkRi I know it look ugly.. I just followed your example, obviously you can put the name you want

Comment: @LkRi now, look I changed it, even every time you call the random method, you store it in the RANDOM variable

Comment: Using a `classmethod` your `RANDOM` signature should be `def RANDOM(cls): and your line can me `RANDOM = random.choice(list(cls))`

Comment: @LkRi now I understood your question

Comment: @EthanFurman forget the class method, I misunderstood the question

Comment: Your previous answer was better.  ;)  `__getattribute__` is easy to get wrong, and overkill for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

As `RANDOM` is not *really* an item in your enumeration, I think a more coherent approach would be to keep it precisely as a method and *not an attribute* (it isn't after all!).

```
import random
import enum


class Gender(enum.Enum):
    MALE = 'male'
    FEMALE = 'female'

    @staticmethod
    def random():
        return random.choice(list(Gender))
```

Then, you could transfer the "I'm not choosing" behaviour to the function where it actually makes more sense.

```
def full_name(gender=None):
    if gender is None:
        gender = Gender.random()
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation : "An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique, **constant** values."
You need to switch to another representation like a class.

Comment: Why? Keeping an `Enum` has its advantages, notably using types for the `Gender`

Comment: Well I think that the pythonic way would simply be to make a fonction that return a random Gender outside of the enum...

Comment: Using an `Enum` is fine.  Using `RANDOM` as a non-constant is not.

Answer (score 0):

Although modifying the class may be clearer and DRY-er in many cases, if you're only doing this once or don't want to modify the enum you could do:

`random.choice([enm.value for enm in Gender])`

Answer (score 0):

Another option that works for your goal is:

```
from enum import Enum
import random

class Gender(Enum):
    MALE = object()
    FEMALE = object()

    @classmethod
    def get_random_gender(cls):
        gender = random.choice(cls._member_names_)
        return gender.lower()


print(Gender.get_random_gender())
>> female
```