# Custom enum creation in Python

Tags: python, enums

I can easily create a class like

```
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
  BOB = "bob"
  RALPH = "ralph"
  ETC = "etc"
```

Then I can assign variables by enum value:

`a = MyEnum('bob')`

**However** -- I want to assign variables by things that could be the correct value.  I.e., I'd like to do

```
a = MyEnum('bob')
b = MyEnum('Bob')
c = MyEnum('BOB')
```

and have them all work, and all map to the same enum value.

Is there a way of doing this without making a factory method?  I've currently defined a `create` method, so `a = MyEnum.create('Bob')` works, but I'd like things to be seamless.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are looking for is called `_missing_` and is available in the stdlib as of Python3.6, and in `aenum`<sup>1</sup> as of 2.0.

```
class MyEnum(Enum):

    BOB = "bob"
    RALPH = "ralph"
    ETC = "etc"

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        for member in cls:
            if member.value == value.lower():
                return member
```

If `_missing_` fails to return a `MyEnum` member then `EnumMeta` will raise an exception (so `_missing_` doesn't have to worry about that part)<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

<sup>2</sup> Thanks, Aran-Fey, for bringing that up.

Comment: You should probably raise a `ValueError` in `_missing_`, otherwise things like `MyEnum('a')` just return `None`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey:  `EnumMeta` checks for that -- if the return value is not an instance of the Enum (`MyEnum` in this case) then an exception is raised automatically... `ValueError` IIRC).

Comment: No exception is raised when I call `MyEnum('a')`. (Python 3.7 and stdlib `enum.Enum`)

Comment: @Aran-Fey:  Huh.  It works correctly in `aenum`.   Would you like to file a bug report at bugs.python.org?

Comment: [Done.](https://bugs.python.org/issue34536)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by subclassing [`EnumMeta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum-classes), which is the [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) responsible for defining the [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method that's invoked by `MyEnum('Bob')`.

```
import enum

class CaseInsensitiveEnum(enum.EnumMeta):
    def __call__(self, string):
        string = string.lower()  # convert the string to lowercase
        return super().__call__(string)

class MyEnum(enum.Enum, metaclass=CaseInsensitiveEnum):
  BOB = "bob"
  RALPH = "ralph"
  ETC = "etc"
```

(Keep in mind that all the enum values have to be lowercase; i.e. `BOB = 'Bob'` would not work.)

Demonstration:

```
>>> MyEnum('Bob')
<MyEnum.BOB: 'bob'>
>>> MyEnum('Bob') is MyEnum.BOB
True
```

Comment: Subclassing `EnumMeta`  is dangerous -- see [`When and where...`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43730305/208880).