# IntEnum returning missing ints in _missing_ throws TypeError

Tags: python

In Python 3.6 it was possible for a class inheriting from `IntEnum` to use the `_missing_` function to return `ints` that, while not valid values, would not crash when parsing incoming data.

```py
class ByteEnum(IntEnum):
    ENUM_VALUE=0

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        if (0<=value<=0xFF) and (value == int(value)):
            return value
        raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
```

When calling ByteEnum(13) i would expect to receive 13. This worked in python 3.6, but in 3.7 it throws a TypeError.

What can I do to have the ByteEnum have the same behaviour it had in Python 3.6, where any integer specified in the `_missing_` function would be allowed. Preferably without having to specify all missing values, or reverting to Python 3.6.

log:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> from enum import IntEnum
>>> class ByteEnum(IntEnum):
...     ENUM_VALUE=0
... 
...     @classmethod
...     def _missing_(cls, value):
...         if (0<=value<=0xFF) and (value == int(value)):
...             return value
...         raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
... 
>>> ByteEnum(13)
ValueError: 13 is not a valid ByteEnum

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\enum.py", line 310, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\enum.py", line 564, in __new__
    raise exc
TypeError: error in ByteEnum._missing_: returned 13 instead of None or a valid member
```

I have been digging a little bit further and it looks like it is an intentional change: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9147. However this still leaves me with the question: what must I return from *missing* to make missing values work?

Comment: You haven't asked us a question. What are you trying to achieve or understand here?

Comment: What can I do to make calling ByteEnum(x) succeed if x is in the valid range for a byte

Comment: In both, 3.6.4 and 3.7.0, this works for me. Please add the full traceback of the TypeError and your 3.7 interpreter's micro version to the question.

Comment: I've added the log and i'm using 3.7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new behavior fixes [bpo-34536](https://bugs.python.org/issue34536) and was backported into [Python 3.7.2 rc1](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#id31). The relevant commit is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/019f0a0cb85ebc234356415f3638b9bd77528e55). The issue leading to the bpo and the subsequent fix was brought up in the comments of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063986/custom-enum-creation-in-python/52064774#52064774).

The old behavior did not do type checking on what `_missing_` returns. In your case, as you state, it returns the integer value, whereas it should return the respective `ByteEnum` instance for that integer.

Following the recipe from the [original implementation in `Flag`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aee260f1c4d32bf67edec209d949294d4dc403c1/Lib/enum.py#L699-L727), you can make your enum behave in the *intended* way.

```
import sys
from enum import IntEnum

class ByteEnum(IntEnum):
    ENUM_VALUE = 0

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, int) and 0 <= value <= 0xFF:
            return cls._create_pseudo_member_(value)
        return None # will raise the ValueError in Enum.__new__

    @classmethod
    def _create_pseudo_member_(cls, value):
        pseudo_member = cls._value2member_map_.get(value, None)
        if pseudo_member is None:
            new_member = int.__new__(cls, value)
            # I expect a name attribute to hold a string, hence str(value)
            # However, new_member._name_ = value works, too 
            new_member._name_ = str(value) 
            new_member._value_ = value
            pseudo_member = cls._value2member_map_.setdefault(value, new_member)
        return pseudo_member

print(sys.version)
print(ByteEnum(13))
print(ByteEnum(1337))
```

Output:

```
3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
ByteEnum.13    
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
ValueError: 1337 is not a valid ByteEnum
```

To get back to your *expected* behavior of your `ByteEnum` returning the value directly, you'd have to override `__new__` to restore the old behavior.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, I don't need it to be an int, this is a lot cleaner thanks!

Comment: I have found one issue with this solution `int(ByteEnum(13))` gives 0, I fixed this by adding `__int__` and `__index__` that return `self._value_` which fixes that issue

Comment: @shommersom: The correct fix is changing the line `new_member = int.__new__(cls)`, which always creates a `0`, to `new_member = int.__new__(cls, value)`.

Comment: This will not work from Python 3.11 and onwards as the `enum` module reserves `_sunder_` names for internal use.  A solution is to make `_create_pseudo_member_` a nested method of `_missing_`.