# Allowing a specific set of undefined values in enums

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Given an enum like this:

```py
class Result(IntEnum):
    A = 0 
    B = 1
    C = 3
```

I'd like to be able to create new enum members dynamically, but only if the value is within a given range. For example, given:

```py
class Result(IntEnum, valid_range=(4, 10)):
    A = 0 
    B = 1
    C = 3
```

I'd expect the following behaviour:

- `Result(10)` would be ok, returning an instance of the enum where `.value` is set to 10.
- `Result(0)` would return `Result.A`
- `Result(20)` or `Result("hello")` would raise a `ValueError`

---

**Why?**

This is for the BACnet standard - a building management/HVAC protocol. Grossly simplified it defines a standard set of message types (for example: `READ`, `WRITE`, `LIST`) which map to integer values. I've modelled these as an enum:

```py
class MessageType(IntEnum):
    READ = 0
    WRITE = 1
    LIST = 2
```

This is then used as follows:

```py
@dataclass
class Message:
    message_type: MessageType
    data: bytes

def decode(raw: bytes) -> Message:
    message_type = MessageType(unpack("!H", bytes[:2]))
    data = bytes[2:]
    return Message(message_type=message_type, data=data)
```

The protocol also allows for vendors to define their own message types but limits them to a specific range of values (i.e. between 10 and 20).

*Options considered:*

- Define each value as an additional enum attribute (i.e. `MessageType.VENDOR_10`) explicitly or dynamically but the number of valid values can be in the millions, most of which will not be used.
- Don't use an enum, just an `int`, an int `TypeAlias`, or just a custom class.
- Change the type annotation on `Message` to `int | MessageType` and when decoding, attempt to create a `MessageType`, catching the `ValueError` and assigning the int.

Comment: Which instance of `Result` would be returned by `Result(10)`?

Comment: You could try implementing `_missing_` but as far as I understand it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063986/custom-enum-creation-in-python

Comment: This sort of defeats the purpose of an enumerated type, as you aren't actually enumerating all the possible values.

Comment: `_missing_` only helps if I want to return an existing instance :( Ideally it would either a) create a new instance, add it to members, etc similar to how Enum does when the class is first created, or b) just return a temporary instance that lives as the calling context does.

Comment: Re defeating the point of a enum - I would agree in most cases. Though in this case I'm implementing a standard where some integers are defined by the standard to have very specific names, while other integers are valid, they are not defined in the standard. 

Here's an example not using enum's https://github.com/JoelBender/bacpypes/blob/master/py25/bacpypes/basetypes.py#L312-L318

Comment: Can you add an example of how you would use this?

Comment: @EthanFurman sure! I've added an extra section to the question outlining the use case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but requires Python 3.9 or better, and does use one currently undocumented data structure (`_value2member_map_`):

```py
from enum import IntEnum

class RangedEnum(IntEnum):

    def __repr__(self):
        if self._name_:
            return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}.{self._name_}: {self._value_}>"
        else:
            return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}: {self._value_}>"

    def __init_subclass__(cls, valid_range):
        cls.valid_range = valid_range

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        start, stop = cls.valid_range
        if start <= value <= stop:
            member = int.__new__(cls, value)
            member._name_ = None
            member._value_ = value
            cls._value2member_map_[value] = member
            return member


class Result(RangedEnum, valid_range=(4, 10)):
    A = 0
    B = 1
    C = 3
```

and some light test code:

```py
>>> for v in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11):
...     try:
...         Result(v)
...     except ValueError:
...         print('nope on', v)
... 
<Result.A: 0>
<Result.B: 1>
nope on 2
<Result.C: 3>
<Result: 4>
<Result: 5>
<Result: 9>
<Result: 10>
nope on 11
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.