# Python Lazy Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I'm trying to create an `enum.Enum` with lazy evaluation.

According to the docs:

> An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique, constant values. Within an enumeration, the members can be compared by identity, and the enumeration itself can be iterated over.

I would say my case still falls within this definition. The values are still unique and constant, I would just like them to be initialised only when necessary. This could be because initialisation is time-consuming, relies on other `Enum` members, has circular dependencies with other `Enum`s, or (in my current case) because initialisation requires a running `QGuiApplication`, and I would like my module to still be importable (but keep that specific enum unusable) if one is not running (there are of course other ways to get around this specific requirement, but I'd like to implement this `Enum` class regardless).

Since [we are only supposed to subclass `EnumMeta` in rare cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43730306/5769814), I wanted to do this by subclassing `Enum` itself:

```
class Lazy:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class LazyEnum(Enum):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        result = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if name == 'value' and isinstance(result, Lazy):
            result = self._lazy_init(result.value)
            self.__setattr__(name, result)
        return result
```

The idea is to mark some values as `Lazy` to be initialised later. However, my sample code:

```
class MyEnum(LazyEnum):
    X = Lazy('x')
    Y = Lazy('y')
    Z = 'z'

    def _lazy_init(self, value):
        print(f"Evaluating {value}")
        return value * 2

print(MyEnum.X.value)
print(MyEnum.X)
print(MyEnum.X.value)
```

raises the error:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

How would I get around this issue?

Comment: Try to use `object.__setattr__`

Comment: So you want the member to exist, but only have it's value set at a later time?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `object.__setattr__(name, result)` raises `TypeError:  expected 2 arguments, got 1`. Changing it to `object.__setattr__(self, name, result)` again raises the same error described in the original post. The same goes for `setattr(self, name, result)`.

Comment: @EthanFurman I want the value to be initialised the first time the member's value is accessed (such as with `MyEnum.X.value`).

Comment: In your above example, is it the first `print(MyEnum.X.value)` or the second `print(MyEnum.X.value)` that raises the error?

Comment: It's the first one. Even if I delete the 2nd and 3rd `print` statement, the error still persists.

Comment: Will these "lazy" members get actual values all at once, or as needed?  Could they get them all at once?  (In other words, you load the GUI, then you can update all the members with their final values.)

Comment: I suppose that would be fine for all the described use cases, other than the computationally expensive initialisation one (and I'm not sure enums were intended for that particular use in any case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the source code of `Enum` and I solved this issue by setting the `_value_` attribute directly, rather than the `value` property. The solution feels somewhat hacky to me, but it seems to work:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta


class AbstractEnumMeta(EnumMeta, ABCMeta):
    pass


class Lazy:
    def __init__(self, *lazy_init_arguments):
        self.args = lazy_init_arguments


class LazyEnum(Enum, metaclass=AbstractEnumMeta):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        result = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if name == 'value' and isinstance(result, Lazy):
            result = self._lazy_init(*result.args)
            setattr(self, '_value_', result)
        return result

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def _lazy_init(cls, *args):
        return args


class MyEnum(LazyEnum):
    X = Lazy('x')
    Y = Lazy('y')
    Z = 'z'

    @classmethod
    def _lazy_init(cls, value):
        print(f"Lazy init of {value}")
        return value * 2


>>> MyEnum.Z
MyEnum.Z
>>> MyEnum.Z.value
'z'
>>> MyEnum.X
MyEnum.X
>>> MyEnum.X.value
Lazy init of x
'xx'
>>> MyEnum.X.value
'xx'
```