# Create an Enum with a bitfield

Tags: python, enums, bit-fields

First a bit of context : I want to process various documents and detect for each one which european  countries have been mentioned.

Example :

```py
EU_COUNTRIES = (
    "Austria",
    "Belgium",
    "Bulgaria",
    "Croatia"
)  # 4 out of the 27
```

To optimize ram consumption (and avoid 27 columns) I'm going to use a bitfield.
For a document where Austria and Bulgaria are mentioned, the bitfield equals to 5.

I'd like to have an enum to help testing against the bitfield.

For example : is Bulgaria mentioned in this document ?

What I expect : `5 & Country.Bulgaria == True`.

What I've tried :

```py
from enum import Enum

class Country(Enum):
    Austria = 1
    Belgium = 2
    Bulgaria = 4
    Croatia = 8

print(5 & Country.Bulgaria)
```

I've created this enum but got error : `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Country'`

How can I achieve the goal (enum or other solution).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: as a side note, python has the `set` type for this kind of stuff.

Comment: My goal is to use the bitfield to store into pandas or numpy as uint32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work with an `IntEnum` : "Enum where members are also (and must be) ints".

Additionally you can build your enum by using the [functional syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).
Combined with bitshift operations it allows to easily generate the enum.

```py
from enum import IntEnum

Country = IntEnum("Country", {c:1<<i for i, c in enumerate(EU_COUNTRIES)})
```

Answer (score 2):

`Flag` was created for this purpose (or `IntFlag` if you need to work directly with `int`s).

@0x0fba's usage of the [Functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) is excellent; if your countries are in a separate file you might want to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43730306/208880) instead to create the flag.

Either way, once you have a `Country` class you would use it something like:

```
affected_countries = Country(5)  # `5` would actually be taken from the data
if Country.Bulgaria in affected_countries:
    # do stuff
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.