# Python 3.10+ deconstructing an over engineered solution to better understand how metaclasses work with properties, static methods, and classmethods

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, metaclass, abc

## TL;DR

This question examines an over-engineered example of python metaclasses and dataclasses to create a `LiteralEnum` (for validating a *string*ly-typed keyword argument) like `LinkageMethod` and a `KeywordsArgumentBaseClass` for making wrappers around SciPy methods like `SciPyLinkage`. The author would like to know how to best distinguish when something should be a `property`, `staticmethod`, `classmethod`, or `instance` method.

As to why someone would do this?

- to override default keyword arguments of scipy methods
- to expose keyword arguments that might be hidden under `**kwargs` and which get passed to another method for better developer experience.
- to modify default behavior of scipy methods e.g. add some optional preprocessing / post processing and be able to distinguish which parameters belong to the method and which to the custom handling.

## Disclaimer

Given the above explanation there is a lot of code and the M*.W.E. is not so minimal (as complexity is one of the key reasons to avoid metaclass usage especially in python which favors simplicity and readability)

## Question(s)

### Newbie question

I am new to using metaclasses. Are the `LiteralEnum` classes at least "pythonic"?

### `staticmethod` vs `classmethod` vs `property` at the metaclass / class level?

The `KeywordArgumentsMeta` and `KeywordArgumentsMixin` classes setup some useful attributes for retrieving a dictionary
of keyword arguments. With `KeywordArgumentsBaseClass` combining the `KeywordArgumentsMixin` and `ClassMethodSignatureMixin`.

This is where I am conflicted:

```
@dataclass
class BaseExample(KeywordArgumentsBaseClass):
    _: KW_ONLY
    strvar: str = 'default'
    intvar: int = 2


@dataclass
class ChildExample(BaseExample):
    _: KW_ONLY
    thirdvar: str = 'three'
    fourth: int = 4


ChildExample.keywords
> ['thirdvar', 'fourth']

ChildExample.ikeywords
> ['strvar', 'intvar']

ChildExample.akeywords
> ['strvar', 'intvar', 'thirdvar', 'fourth']


ChildExample.defaults
> {'thirdvar': 'three', 'fourth': 4}

...


ChildExample().kwargs
> {'thirdvar': 'three', 'fourth': 4}
...


ChildExample().params(**{'thirdvar': 'new', 'banana': 3})
> {'thirdvar': 'new', 'fourth': 4}
```

I am conflicted because I want to make a wrapper for SciPy Methods

```
@dataclass
class SciPyMethod(KeywordArgumentsBaseClass):    
    _: KW_ONLY

    @classmethod
    def get_method(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    @classmethod
    def call_scipy(cls, **kws):
        inst = cls()
        
        method = cls.get_method()
        params = inst.prepare_params(func = method, scope = locals(), **kws)    
        result = method(**cls.kwargs)
        raise NotImplementedError

    def call_scipy(self, **kwargs):
        cls = type(self)
        method = type(self).get_method()
        params = self.prepare_params(func = method, scope = locals(), **kwargs)
        print(params)
        raise NotImplementedError
        result = method(**cls.kwargs)
        return result

    def __call__(self, x: NPArray, **kwargs) -> NPArray:
        method = self.get_method()
```

but I need both classmethods and instance methods for this to work.

Since there are classmethods for getting default params, instance methods for getting current params, and
the `prepare_params` methods for getting params for a function signature how can I make `call_scipy` work with both as classmethod and instance method?

How could this be simplified / make more pythonic?

#### Usefulness of `ClassMethodSignatureMixin`

While `ClassMethodSignaturePriority` seems useful at first glace, I am not actually sure if it is useful at all consider:

```py
class Example(ClassMethodSignatureMixin):
    _: KW_ONLY
    test_var: str = 'default'


    def foo(self, test_var: Optional[str] = None, **kwargs):
        params = self.prepare_params(func=self.foo, scope=locals(), **kwargs)
        print(params)
        return params
```

The `prepare_params` method, without knowing the function signature will can handle explictly named keywords
in the func which might be defined or passed in via **kwargs.

However, test_var must either be defined in the class, passed in as a (positional) keyword argument or passed in via **kwargs.
Python will naturally prevent `Example().foo(test_var='fine', **{'test_var': 'causes error'})`.

The `prepare_params` method on the other hand is useful as it filters keyword arguments for the function signature only, using the local scope
which helps make sure that in the case of `foo` method, the value of `test_var` gets put into params.

Or to restate more cleanly.  Given a function with an unknown number of keyword arguments (like `test_var` in `foo`), `prepare_params`
uses `locals()` and `**kwargs` to make sure there is a single dictionary to check for the values of the keyword arguments.

## Code

### Imports

```py
import os, inspect
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, scipy as sp
from dataclasses import dataclass, KW_ONLY
from enum import Enum, StrEnum, EnumMeta, auto
from typing import Optional, Callable, List, Tuple, Any, Dict, Union, Literal
```

### LiteralEnum

#### MetaClass

```py
class LiteralEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    '''LiteralEnumMeta

    See Also:
    --------
    - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730305/when-should-i-subclass-enummeta-instead-of-enum
    - https://peps.python.org/pep-3115/
    - https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#class-attribute-lookup
    '''

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases, **kwargs):
        enum_dict = super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs)
        #print('PREPARE: <enum_dict> = \t', enum_dict)

        # NOTE: this will through an error since we are using StrEnum
        # enum_dict['_default'] = None
        return enum_dict

    def __init__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(clsname, bases, clsdict, **kwargs) 
        # print('INIT: <clsdict> = \t', clsname, clsdict) 

    def __new__(
        metacls, cls, bases, clsdict, *, 
        default: Optional[str] = None, elements: Optional[List[str]] = None
    ):
        # print('NEW: <clsdict> = \t', cls, clsdict)
        if elements is not None:
            for element in elements:
                clsdict[element.upper()] = auto()

        new_cls = super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict)

        # NOTE: this will result in TypeError: cannot extend 
        if default:            
            setattr(new_cls, '_default', default)
        
        return new_cls  

    @property
    def members(cls):
        # NOTE: could also use cls._member_names_
        return [member.name for member in cls]

    @property
    def values(cls):
        return [member.value for member in cls]
    
    @property
    def items(cls):
        return list(zip(cls.members, cls.values))
```

#### LiteralEnum

```py
class LiteralEnum(StrEnum, metaclass=LiteralEnumMeta):
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        for member in cls:
            if member.value.lower() == value.lower():
                return member

        default = getattr(cls, cls._default, None)
        return default
```

#### Decorators

```py
def enum_default(default: str = ''):
    def wrapper(cls):
        cls._default = default
        return cls
    return wrapper

def enum_set_attr(name: str = 'attr', attr: str = 'data'):
    def wrapper(cls):
        setattr(cls, f'_{name}', attr)
        return cls
    return wrapper

def set_method(method):
    def decorator(cls):
        cls.method = method
        return cls
    return decorator
```

### SciPy LiteralEnum Examples

#### Linkage

```py
@enum_default('SINGLE')
class LinkageMethod(LiteralEnum):
    '''
    See Also
    --------    
    scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage : Performs hierarchical/agglomerative clustering on the condensed distance matrix y.
        https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html
    '''
    SINGLE = auto()
    COMPLETE = auto()
    AVERAGE = auto()
    WEIGHTED = auto()
    CENTROID = auto()
    MEDIAN = auto()
    WARD = auto()
```

#### PDistMetric

```py
@enum_default('EUCLIDEAN')
class PDistMetric(LiteralEnum):
    '''
    See Also
    -------- 
    scipy.spatial.distance.pdist : Compute the pairwise distances between observations in n-dimensional space.
        https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist
    '''
    BRAYCURTIS = auto()
    CANBERRA = auto()
    CHEBYSHEV = auto()
    CITYBLOCK = auto()
    CORRELATION = auto()
    COSINE = auto()
    DICE = auto()
    EUCLIDEAN = auto()
    HAMMING = auto()
    JACCARD = auto()
    JENSENSHANNON = auto()
    KULCZYNSKI1 = auto()
    MAHALANOBIS = auto()
    MATCHING = auto()
    MINKOWSKI = auto()
    ROGERSTANIMOTO = auto()
    RUSSELLRAO = auto()
    SEUCLIDEAN = auto()
    SOKALMICHENER = auto()
    SOKALSNEATH = auto()
    SQEUCLIDEAN = auto()
    YULE = auto()
```

#### ScoreMethod

```py
@enum_default('ZSCORE')
class ScoreMethod(LiteralEnum):
    '''
    See Also
    --------
    scipy.stats.zscore : Compute the z-score.    
    scipy.stats.gzscore : Compute the geometric standard score.
    '''
    ZSCORE = auto()
    GZSCORE = auto()
```

### ClassMethodSignaturePriority

```py
@enum_default('OBJ')
@enum_set_attr('attr', 'data')
class ClassMethodSignaturePriority(LiteralEnum):    
    OBJ = auto()
    ARG = auto()
    KWS = auto()

    def get(self, obj: object, attr: Optional[str] = None, arg: Optional[Any] = None, **kws) -> Union[NPArray, DataFrame, Any]:
        match self:
            # try and get `attr` from `obj` defaulting back to `arg`
            case ClassMethodSignaturePriority.OBJ:
                val = getattr(obj, attr, arg)
                if val is None:
                    return ClassMethodSignaturePriority('ARG').get(obj, attr, arg, **kws)
            
            # use `arg` as is unless it is None, then try and get `attr` from `obj`
            case ClassMethodSignaturePriority.ARG:
                val = arg
                if val is None:
                    return ClassMethodSignaturePriority('KWS').get(obj, attr, arg, **kws)                    
                
            # use `kws` assuming `attr` is in `kwargs` falling back to arg then try and get `attr` from `obj`
            case ClassMethodSignaturePriority.KWS:
                val = kws.get(attr, arg)   
            
            case _:
                pass

        if val is None:
            val = getattr(obj, attr, arg)

        if isinstance(val, (list, np.ndarray, )):
            val = np.asanyarray(val)

        return val

    @classmethod
    def prioritize(cls, obj: object, attr: str, arg: Optional[Any] = None, priority: Literal['obj', 'arg', 'kws'] = 'obj', **kws) -> Union[NPArray, DataFrame, Any]:
        return cls(priority).get(obj, attr, arg, **kws)

    @classmethod
    def _pobj(cls, obj: object, attr: str, arg: Optional[Any] = None, **kws) -> Union[NPArray, DataFrame, Any]:
        return cls.prioritize(obj, attr, arg, 'obj', **kws)

    @classmethod
    def _pargs(cls, obj: object, attr: str, arg: Optional[Any] = None, **kws) -> Union[NPArray, DataFrame, Any]:
        return cls.prioritize(obj, attr, arg, 'args', **kws)

    @classmethod
    def _pkws(cls, obj: object, attr: str, arg: Optional[Any] = None, **kws) -> Union[NPArray, DataFrame, Any]:
        return cls.prioritize(obj, attr, arg, 'kws', **kws)
```

#### Mixin

```py
@dataclass
class ClassMethodSignatureMixin:
    def get_val(self, attr: str, arg: Optional[Any] = None, prioritize: Union[Literal['obj', 'arg', 'kws'], ClassMethodSignaturePriority] = 'arg', **kws):    
        # by default we will prioritize `arg` over `self` as `arg` might overwrite `self`'s attribute
        # arg --(fallbacks to)--> kws --(fallbacks to)--> self
        priority = ClassMethodSignaturePriority(prioritize)
        return priority.get(self, attr=attr, arg=arg, **kws)

    def _prioritize_kws(self, attr: str, arg: Optional[Any] = None, **kws):
        return self.get_arg(attr, arg, prioritize='kws', **kws)

    def _prioritize_arg(self, attr: str, arg: Optional[Any] = None, **kws):
        return self.get_arg(attr, arg, prioritize='arg', **kws)

    def _prioritize_obj(self, attr: str, arg: Optional[Any] = None, **kws):
        return self.get_arg(attr, arg, prioritize='obj', **kws)
    
    def get_arg(self, attr: str, func: Callable, scope: Dict[str, Any]):
        args = inspect.getfullargspec(func).args
        if attr in args and attr in scope:
            return scope[attr]
        return None
    
    def get_tuple(self, attr: str,func: Callable, scope: Dict[str, Any], **kws) -> Tuple[Any, Any, Any]:
        obj = getattr(self, attr, None)
        arg = self.get_arg(attr, func, scope)
        kwa = kws.get(attr, None)
        return obj, arg, kwa
    
    def update_params(self, **kws):
        params = self.aparams()
        for k, v in self.kwargs:
            v = self.get_val(attr=k, prioritize='kws', **kws)
            params[k] = v
        return params
```

### KeywordArguments

#### KeywordArgumentsMeta

```py
class KeywordArgumentsMeta(type):    
    @staticmethod
    def get_annots_kws(cls) -> list:
        '''Get annotated keyword only argument names'''
        annots = list(cls.__annotations__.keys())
        if '_' not in annots:
            return []
        return annots[annots.index('_') + 1:] 

    @staticmethod
    def get_cls_kws(cls) -> list:
        '''
        NOTES
        -----
        - if using inheritance this will get all keyword only arguments
        '''
        return inspect.getfullargspec(cls.__init__).kwonlyargs

    @staticmethod
    def attr_dict(obj: object, attrs: list) -> dict:
        return dict((k, getattr(obj, k, None)) for k in attrs)

    @staticmethod
    def inst_dict(inst: object, attr: str = 'defaults'):        
        attrs = getattr(type(inst), attr).items()
        return dict((k, getattr(inst, k, v)) for k, v in attrs)
                
    @property
    def keywords(cls) -> list:        
        '''Get current keyword only argument names'''
        return cls.get_annots_kws(cls)

    @property
    def ikeywords(cls) -> list:
        '''Get inherited keyword only argument names'''
        ignore = cls.keywords
        result = list()
        is_new = lambda kw: kw not in result and kw not in ignore
        for c in inspect.getmro(cls):
            if c is not object:
                new_kws = cls.get_annots_kws(c)
                result.extend(list(filter(is_new, new_kws)))
        return result
    
    @property
    def akeywords(cls) -> list:
        '''Get all keyword only argument names'''
        result = list()
        is_new = lambda kw: kw not in result
        for c in inspect.getmro(cls):
            if c is not object:
                new_kws = cls.get_annots_kws(c)
                result.extend(list(filter(is_new, new_kws)))
        return result
    
    @property
    def defaults(cls) -> dict:
        '''Get default keyword arguments only values'''
        instance = cls()
        return cls.attr_dict(instance, cls.keywords)  

    @property
    def idefaults(cls) -> dict:
        '''Get inherited default keyword arguments only values'''
        instance = cls()
        return cls.attr_dict(instance, cls.ikeywords)

    @property
    def adefaults(cls) -> dict:
        '''Get all default keyword arguments only values'''
        instance = cls()
        return cls.attr_dict(instance, cls.akeywords)
```

#### KeywordArgumentsMixin

```py
@dataclass
class KeywordArgumentsMixin(metaclass=KeywordArgumentsMeta):
    _: KW_ONLY

    @property
    def kwargs(self) -> dict:
        '''Get instance specific default keyword arguments only values'''
        return type(self).inst_dict(self, attr='defaults')
        
    @property
    def ikwargs(self) -> dict:
        '''Get instance inherited default keyword arguments only values'''
        return type(self).inst_dict(self, attr='idefaults')

    @property
    def akwargs(self) -> dict:
        '''Get instance all default keyword arguments only values'''
        return type(self).inst_dict(self, attr='adefaults')

    def _merge_kws_to_dict(self, params: dict, **kwargs) -> dict:
        '''Only overwrite values in params with kwargs if key is in params'''
        values = params.copy()
        values.update(dict((k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in values))
        return values

    def params(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        '''Get instance default keyword arguments only values but update with kwargs'''
        return self._merge_kws_to_dict(self.kwargs, **kwargs)

    def iparams(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        '''Get instance inherited keyword arguments only values but update with kwargs'''
        return self._merge_kws_to_dict(self.ikwargs, **kwargs)
        
    def aparams(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        '''Get instance all default keyword arguments only values but update with kwargs'''
        return self._merge_kws_to_dict(self.akwargs, **kwargs)
```

### KeywordArgumentsBaseClass

```py
@dataclass
class KeywordArgumentsBaseClass(KeywordArgumentsMixin, ClassMethodSignatureMixin):
    def prepare_params(self, func: Optional[Callable] = None, scope: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None, **kws) -> dict:
        params = self.aparams()

        for k, v in self.akwargs.items():
            
            arg = None
            if func and scope:
                arg = self.get_arg(attr=k, func=func, scope=scope)
            
            v = self.get_val(attr=k, arg=arg, prioritize='arg', **kws)
            params[k] = v

        return params
```

### SciPyLinkage

```py
#| export
@dataclass
class SciPyLinkage(KeywordArgumentsBaseClass):
    _: KW_ONLY
    
    method: LinkageMethod = LinkageMethod.SINGLE
    metric: PDistMetric = PDistMetric.CORRELATION
    optimal_ordering: bool = True

    def __post_init__(self):        
        self.method = LinkageMethod(self.method)
        self.metric = PDistMetric(self.metric)

    def __call__(self, x: NPArray, **kwargs) -> NPArray:
        l_func = sp.cluster.hierarchy.linkage
        params = self.prepare_params(func=l_func, scope=locals(), **kwargs)        
        print('LINKAGE', params)
        # linkage = l_func(x, **params)
        # return linkage
```

Comment: sorry. I won't be voting to close, but I think this is not really answerable in the scope of stackoverflow questions (Of couse, someone could always step in to do so). 
I'd suggest contracting a couple hours of consulting to get briefed into this - as it won't be something easy to track or digest with gratis resources.

Comment: (a) this all needs to be deleted and replaced with a stubs library, but (b) this question needs to be moved to Code Review from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Whether you get a useful answer, depends on who sees it, and how much time they are willing to spend reading, thinking, and writing.  I agree this looks more like a CR topic, dealing with code style rather than a specific  bug.

Comment: This is too open-ended / opinion-based to really have a useful answer or be OT here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of user suggestion