# Get Enum name from multiple values python

Tags: python, enums, multiple-value

I'm trying to get the name of a enum given one of its multiple values:

```
class DType(Enum):
    float32 = ["f", 8]
    double64 = ["d", 9]
```

when I try to get one value giving the name it works:

```
print DType["float32"].value[1]  # prints 8
print DType["float32"].value[0]  # prints f
```

but when I try to get the name out of a given value only errors will come:

```
print DataType(8).name
print DataType("f").name
```

> raise ValueError("%s is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.**name**))

> ValueError: 8 is not a valid DataType

> ValueError: f is not a valid DataType

Is there a way to make this? Or am I using the wrong data structure?

Comment: Enums can't have multiple value per name. Why do you need this, is one of these an alias? When would use use `'f'` and when `9`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) library<sup>1</sup>, which would look like this:

```
from aenum import MultiValueEnum

class DType(MultiValueEnum):
    float32 = "f", 8
    double64 = "d", 9
```

and in use:

```
>>> DType("f")
<DType.float32: 'f'>

>>> DType(9)
<DType.double64: 'd'>
```

As you can see, the first value listed is the canonical value, and shows up in the `repr()`.

If you want all the possible values to show up, or need to use the stdlib `Enum` (Python 3.4+), then the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107853/208880) is the basis of what you want (and will also work with `aenum`):

```
class DType(Enum):
    float32 = "f", 8
    double64 = "d", 9

    def __new__(cls, *values):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        # first value is canonical value
        obj._value_ = values[0]
        for other_value in values[1:]:
            cls._value2member_map_[other_value] = obj
        obj._all_values = values
        return obj

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s.%s: %s>' % (
                self.__class__.__name__,
                self._name_,
                ', '.join([repr(v) for v in self._all_values]),
                )
```

and in use:

```
>>> DType("f")
<DType.float32: 'f', 8>

>>> Dtype(9)
<DType.float32: 'd', 9>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: @Ruvalcaba:  Glad to help.  When an answer works for you, you should accept it (click on the green check mark by that answer's score).

Comment: Just change the import to:

from aenum import MultiValueEnum

class DType(MultiValueEnum):    
    float32 = "f", 8
    double64 = "d", 9

Comment: @EthanFurman Do you think `MultiValueEnum` might land into the standard library eventually?

Comment: @Rotareti:  Hard to say.  Having real-world use-cases would help prove the need, but even then `Enum` is meant as a building-block more than a whole bunch of comprehensive solutions.

Comment: How to get "8" or "9"?

Comment: @Nairum, you could create a @ property into Enum class and access with self._all_values[index of value you want to access], for example self._all_values[1].