# change variable type, and relabel variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, analytics

I have uploaded a dataset in Python. I need to do two things. One, change some of my variables, like ID, Gender (which is input as 0 and 1) from float64. I also want to change the input under gender from 0 to male and 1 to female.

I am not sure how to go about the first questions, but the second, I figure I would do a combination of a for loop and if then statements, but I am really confused. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the dataset look like, are you using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say what type you want to change your variables to, all I can suggest is to use casting.

```
x = 0
x_bool = bool(x) # False
x_str = str(x) # '0'
# ...
```

But, for Gender, I would suggest you to create an enum

```
from enum import Enum
class EGender(Enum):
    MALE = 0
    FEMALE = 1
```

Then you can do:

```
x = 0
x_gender = EGender(x) # EGender.MALE
```

**EDIT:** If you really want to have 'male' and 'female' (str types) for your gender attribute, you can use [aenum](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/) to set multiple values for an enumerable. For more information about aenum, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202777/get-enum-name-from-multiple-values-python)