# How to create Python Enum which allows synonyms?

Tags: python, enums

I'm normalising existing, messy data, and I'd like to create an `Enum` which allows synonyms for the canonical names of the members, so that if someone uses a synonym value when instantiating the enum, they will get the canonical one back. Ie.

```py
class TrainOutcome(enum.Enum):
    PASSED = "PASSED"
    SUCCESS = "PASSED" # Deprecated synonym for "PASSED"
    FAILED = "FAILED"
    STARTED = "STARTED"
```

This executes fine, but the resulting enum doesn't behave as expected:

```py
>>> TrainOutcome("PASSED")
<TrainOutcome.PASSED: 'PASSED'>

# I want to get <TrainOutcome.PASSED: 'PASSED'> here as well
>>> TrainOutcome("SUCCESS")
ValueError: 'SUCCESS' is not a valid TrainOutcome

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 309, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 600, in __new__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 584, in __new__
    result = cls._missing_(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 613, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: 'SUCCESS' is not a valid TrainOutcome
```

This is despite the fact that the `__members__` attribute seems to map things exactly the way I was hoping for:

```py
>>> TrainOutcome.__members__
mappingproxy({'PASSED': <TrainOutcome.PASSED: 'PASSED'>, 'SUCCESS': <TrainOutcome.PASSED: 'PASSED'>, 'FAILED': <TrainOutcome.FAILED: 'FAILED'>, 'STARTED': <TrainOutcome.STARTED: 'STARTED'>})
>>> TrainOutcome['SUCCESS']
<TrainOutcome.PASSED: 'PASSED'>
>>> TrainOutcome['PASSED']
<TrainOutcome.PASSED: 'PASSED'>
```

How do I create the enum so that the constructor accepts and returns the same value as indexing the type does?

*Edit*: The existing [Python Enum with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537316/python-enums-with-duplicate-values) doesn't answer my question, since in essence it's trying to achieve the opposite of what I'm after. The OP there wanted to make the resulting values more distinct, I want to make them less distinct. In fact, the ideal solution would be not to have the synonym member at all (since I'm using the resulting `Enum` in SQLAlchemy context, which looks at the member names, not their values), and just silently replace `"SUCCESS"` with `"PASSED"` during construction time, but defining a custom `__init__` on enums that calls `super()` doesn't seem to work.

*Edit:* [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43202777/208880) provides the easiest solution so far: use `aenum.MultiValueEnum`.

Otherwise, here's a homegrown solution that seems to be in the spirit of how you're supposed to do in Python 3.6+, somewhat inspired by @Green Cloak Guy's answer:

```
class EnumSynonymMixin:
    """
    Enum mixin which provides the ability to define synonyms,
    ie. values which can be passed into an enum's constructor, that
    name the same member as one of the defined values, without adding
    any extra members (useful for using with SQLAlchemy's Enum mapping)

    For example:

    class MyEnum(EnumSynonymMixin, enum.Enum):
        FOO = "FOO"
        BAR = "BAR"

        @classmethod
        def synonyms(cls):
            return {"MYFOO": "FOO"}
    
    >>> MyEnum("MYFOO")
    <MyEnum.FOO: 'FOO'>
    """
    @classmethod
    def synonyms(cls):
        """Override to provide a dictionary of synonyms for values that can be
        passed to the constructor"""
        return {}

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, val):
        synonyms = cls.synonyms()
        if val in synonyms:
            return cls.__members__[synonyms[val]]
        return super()._missing(val)


class TrainOutcome(EnumSynonymMixin, enum.Enum):
    PASSED = "PASSED"
    FAILED = "FAILED"
    STARTED = "STARTED"

    @classmethod
    def synonyms(cls):
        return {"SUCCESS": "PASSED"}
```

Comment: @gold_cy: It doesn't seem so, I believe this is asking for the opposite of my problem. I don't care about the duplicate values, I specifically don't want them listed; all I want is so that when my code asks for `TrainOutcome('SUCCESS')`, it gets the same result as if it asked for `TrainOutcome('PASSED')`

Comment: @gold_cy: I already know it doesn't work :). What I'm interested in is knowing how to make it work the way I want, not all the ways in which it doesn't work.

Comment: @gold_cy: No, you're definitely misunderstanding the question. Your dupe candidate is asking for the opposite of what this question wants.

Comment: @gold_cy: no, it isn't what I'm looking for. It still fails with the exact same error. And if you read my question, you'd know that I'm not looking for "label-and-value pairs that are unique (and not aliases)" (to quote the accepted answer), I'm looking for the exact opposite of it! I want an alias that's so much an alias, it disappears from everything except `__members__` and the ability to pass a synonym value into the constructor.

Comment: Hold on - I posted an answer pointing out you need to use `[]` instead of `()`, but looking closer at your question, it looks like you already know that works. Why do you want to use `TrainOutcome('SUCCESS')`? It means the wrong thing. `TrainOutcome['SUCCESS']` means the operation you're trying to perform.

Comment: but what's the point of wanting this?

Comment: @DevLounge: I have existing messy data that contain a bunch of disjoint names that I want to normalise to a well-defined set of names, and I also want this to be a real enum so that it can map into PostgreSQL through SQLAlchemy's built-in support for doing that.

Comment: I suspect this really needs to be a SQLAlchemy question instead of an enum question to find the best resolution to the underlying problem.

Comment: It looks like what you actually have is multiple values for one member.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/43202777/208880 for a `MultiValueEnum` solution.

Comment: @EthanFurman: that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want. Essentially, the class wrapper makes `TrainOutcome(value)` behave like `TrainOutcome[value]` when the former would otherwise produce an error (as in the case you've described, where you're trying to call it with "SUCCESS"). It does this by intercepting the call to `__new__()` and replacing the first argument.

Per comments on your question, you probably shouldn't do this - there's little reason I can think of why `TrainOutcome['SUCCESS']` shouldn't suffice for your needs.

```
def callActsLikeGetitem(c):
    oldnew = c.__new__
    def newwrapper(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return oldnew(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            if len(args) > 0:
                args = (cls[args[0]].name, *args[1:])
            return oldnew(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    c.__new__ = newwrapper
    return c

@callActsLikeGetitem
class TrainOutcome(enum.Enum):
    PASSED = "PASSED"
    SUCCESS = "PASSED" # Deprecated synonym for "PASSED"
    FAILED = "FAILED"
    STARTED = "STARTED"

TrainOutcome("SUCCESS")
# <TrainOutcome.PASSED: 'PASSED'>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer got me reading the docs again and I actually stumbled upon what I think is the intended solution in Python 3.6+, using `_missing_`