# How can I override the enum constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, constructor, overriding

I want to create an enum that stores a binary value, but to which I can pass any value (it will store `value % 2`).

That is : I want to use the "official" `Enum` type from Python3 but change the constructor.

I tried this code :

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    black = 0
    red = 1

    def __new__(cls, value):
        super().__new__(cls, value % 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But I get an error :

```
>>> from ZCasino import *
ValueError: 0 is not a valid Couleur

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/felix/Téléchargements/ZCasino.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Couleur(Enum):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 212, in __new__
    enum_member = __new__(enum_class, *args)
  File "/home/felix/Téléchargements/ZCasino.py", line 18, in __new__
    super().__new__(cls, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 595, in __new__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 579, in __new__
    result = cls._missing_(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 608, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: 0 is not a valid Couleur
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to override \_\_new\_\_ in an enum to parse strings to an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105268/is-it-possible-to-override-new-in-an-enum-to-parse-strings-to-an-instance)

Comment: Yeah, but I did "answer your own question", I thought the question would be flagged as such to people answering ^^''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new class method would probably be a better idea than overriding `__new__`:

```
class Color(Enum):
    black = 0
    red = 1

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, x):
        return cls(x%2)
```

Then

```
>>> Color.from_int(6)
<Color.black: 0>
>>> Color.from_int(7)
<Color.red: 1>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can take advantage of the new `_missing_` method:

```
from aenum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    black = 0
    red = 1
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    #
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        return cls(value % 2)
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Color)
[<Color.black: 0>, <Color.red: 1>]

>>> Color(3)
<Color.red: 1>

>>> Color(8)
<Color.black: 0>
```

`_missing_` was introduced in Python 3.6.  If you need to support earlier Pythons you can use the [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup> library.

**NB** When calling `Color(7)` you are not creating a new `Color`, but getting the existing `<Color.black: 0>` that was created when the Enum itself was created.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `__new__` method *after* the method definition :

([Is it possible to override __new__ in an enum to parse strings to an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105268/is-it-possible-to-override-new-in-an-enum-to-parse-strings-to-an-instance))

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    black = 0
    red = 1

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Couleur.__new__ = lambda cls, value: super(Couleur, cls).__new__(cls, value % 2)
```

Comment: While I wouldn't recommend this method for most purposes, it is a handy trick to keep in mind.