# Selecting Enum value from constructor?

Tags: python, enums

Extending the `Enum` example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), I can add a class method to select the correct enum when only part of its tuple is supplied:

```py
class Planet1(Enum):
    MERCURY = (3.303e23, 2.4397e6)
    VENUS = (4.869e24, 6.0518e6)
    EARTH = (5.976e24, 6.37814e6)
    MARS = (6.421e23, 3.3972e6)

    @classmethod
    def from_partial(cls, mass=None, radius=None):
        for member in cls:
            if member.mass == mass or member.radius == radius:
                return member
        raise ValueError("No planet with these characteristics.")

    def __init__(self, mass, radius):
        self.mass = mass  # in kg
        self.radius = radius  # in m

p1 = Planet1.MARS
p2 = Planet1.from_partial(6.421e23)
p3 = Planet1.from_partial(radius=3.3972e6)
p1 is p2 is p3  # True
```

**I'd like to be able to select one without using the `.from_partial()` method though. Is that possible?**

What I've tried:

```py
class Planet2(Enum):
    MERCURY = (3.303e23, 2.4397e6)
    VENUS = (4.869e24, 6.0518e6)
    EARTH = (5.976e24, 6.37814e6)
    MARS = (6.421e23, 3.3972e6)

    def __init__(self, mass=None, radius= None):
        if mass is None or radius is None:
            for member in Planet2:
                if member.mass == mass or member.radius == radius:
                    self.__dict__ = member.__dict__
        else:
            self.mass = mass  # in kg
            self.radius = radius  # in m

p2a = Planet2.MARS
p2b = Planet2(6.421e23)  # ValueError: 6.421e+23 is not a valid Planet2
p2c = Planet2(radius=3.3972e6) # TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'radius'
```

Is there a way to do this, or does this go against what Enums are intended to be used for? The `self.__dict__ = member.__dict__` looks dodgy, but I'd have thought it would work :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override the enum constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172586/how-can-i-override-the-enum-constructor)

Comment: Why do you want to store the planet mass in an enum that identifies the planet? Seems like an unusual extension to the notion of an enumerated type.

Comment: @jarmod, This is the example given in the official python docs. I think of a python enum as a (small) closed set of related information, rather than just an integer that is given a human-readable name.

Answer (score 2):

Edit for updated question:

The closest you can get would be option 2 below, but you would only be able to specify a value, not which one you wanted (so no keyword arguments).

Given that, I would stick with a separate `from_partial()` classmethod instead

---

You have a couple choices, depending on your use-case:

1. Write your own `__new__` and assign a number to `_value_` and whatever else to other attributes:

```
    class Planet(Enum):
        #
        def __new__(cls, mass):
            value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
            member = object.__new__(cls)
            member._value_ = value
            member.mass = mass
            return obj
        #
        MERCURY = 3.303e23
        VENUS = 4.869e24
        EARTH = 5.976e24
        MARS = 6.421e23
```

2. As of Python 3.6 you can add a `_missing_` method instead of `from_num`:

```
    class Planet(Enum):
        #
        @classmethod
        def _missing_(cls, value):
            for member in cls:
                if member._value_[0] == value:
                    return member
        #
        MERCURY = 1, 3.303e23
        VENUS = 2, 4.869e24
        EARTH = 3, 5.976e24
        MARS = 4, 6.421e23
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Ah, what an honour :) I see that I made my example too concise and your proposed solutions do not work in my actual use case. I've updated the question; it is now closer to the implementation in the docs as well. (I chose my original example to avoid comparing floats, but it seems there is no problem there; my updated `.from_partial` simply works. In my actual use-case, the value tuples contain strings, integers, and other enums.)

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` values should be (ideally opaque) integers, so your use isn't as intended.  For example, if created properly, `Planet(3)` does work:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Planet(Enum):
    MERCURY = 1
    VENUS = 2
    EARTH = 3
    MARS = 4

class Planets:

    def __init__(self):
        ordered_masses = 3.303e23, 4.869e24, 5.976e24, 6.421e23
        self._data = dict((Planet(i),m) for i,m in enumerate(ordered_masses,1))

    def mass(self,planet):
        return _data[planet]

    def display(self):
        for k,v in self._data.items():
            print(k,v)

print(Planet(3))
Planets().display()
```

Output:

```
Planet.EARTH
Planet.MERCURY 3.303e+23
Planet.VENUS 4.869e+24
Planet.EARTH 5.976e+24
Planet.MARS 6.421e+23
```

Comment: I agree that the common case for Enum is opaque values; however, if the OP's use wasn't intended I wouldn't have built in support for it, nor added the examples to the docs.

Comment: @EthanFurman Fair enough, you're the author, but still feels like a misuse of an enumeration and the separation of concerns principle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MarkTolonen. I'm trying to store related information about a not-extendible set of values, and python enums seem perfect for that. It's the first time I'm using them, and I do get your point - feel free to comment [on my actual use case](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/267948/using-python-enums-to)